# grunt with livereload with ftp support

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, livereload

I am forced to work on a webapp which works only on remote server due to cross-domain cookie restrictions. I am used to work with Grunt.js and Yeoman, but now with each change I am forced to wait quite a long time for each upload to the server. Do you know some way to configure Grunt so it can watch for changes and upload only the changed files to the server?

Edit: I am also using coffeescript, jade so this solution should work on grunt compiled files. Also, I am using Webstorm.